# Adding Simple Custom Field to Django -- How to Write South Introspection Rules

Tags: django, django-admin, django-south

I am trying to add a custom field to my Django project that uses [South](http://south.aeracode.org/).  Because of this, I am trying (for the first time) to write [introspection rules for South](http://south.aeracode.org/wiki/MyFieldsDontWork).  I believe my case is the simplest possible as I am simply extending a CharField.  Specifically:

```
class ColorField(models.CharField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['max_length'] = 10
        super(ColorField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['widget'] = ColorPickerWidget
        return super(ColorField, self).formfield(**kwargs)
```

This is from a Django snippet called [jQuery color picker model field](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1261/) for those interested.

Since I am not adding any new attributes, I believe I only have to add these lines of code:

```
from south.modelsinspector import add_introspection_rules
add_introspection_rules([], ["^myproject\.myapp\.models\.ColorField"])
```

It is probably obvious, but where should they go?  Also, is my assumption that this is all I have to do correct?

I have reviewed several questions posted here, but most deal with much more complex introspections.

Per http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customfields.html#where-to-put-the-code, I have tried puttin the code at the top of my models.py file where the custom field is defined.  But this has not worked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple answer: yes, the code should go in the models.py file where the field was defined.  The correct code is:

```
from south.modelsinspector import add_introspection_rules
add_introspection_rules([], ["^myapp\.models\.ColorField"])
```

Not sure why I was putting the project name in there.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that the path to the file is correct. The one you mention looks similar to one I am using, but the path is:

```
add_introspection_rules([], ["^colors\.fields\.ColorField"])
```